# Text File Storing Data

Tags: c#, text-files, streamreader

I have a text file to read in (which is not the problem), The file is divided into three sections each with a different heading i.e. block{A}, Block{B} and Block{C}.

After each block is are lines of text, each line contains a word after "#" which I need to capture.

The tricky bit is all the words in block A have a second meaning or weighting. All words in block A have say a weighting of 1, whilst block B a weighting 2 and block C a weighting 3.

These weight values are not present in the text file and the text file cannot be edited to include them.

So I need a method to read the data (not a problem), check which block its in (look for 'Block{*}') then store away the word after '#' with its weighting (1 or 2 or 3).

I need some suggestions as to the best mechanism to store the data so that it can be compared to as a text box is updated character by character.

The text box string is compared (after each key press) to all the words in the text file or the data extracted from it and if their is a match, the weighting value associated with that word is used by the code.

Comment: ummmm. can you show a sample data please..

Comment: The file contains data like this:-

$ some comments
$ more comments
Block{A}
1234#HELP
4321#TEST
Block{B}
2222#TRAIN
3333#AIRPORT

Comment: sorry about the formatting of my reply, I'm new to the site. How do I do a newline when posting

Answer (score 2):

First off, you can create a simple class to store your data

```
public class Words
{
  public string Word{get;set;}
  public int Weigth{get;set;}
}
```

Then do something like this to process the file:

```
  var words = new List<Words>();
  string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("myFilename");
  int weigth = 0;
  foreach( var line in lines )
  {
    if (line == "block{A}") weigth = 1;
    else if (line == "block{B}") weigth = 2;
    else if (line == "block{C}") weigth = 3;
    else words.Add( new Words{ Word = line.Replace("#",""), Weigth = weigth});
  }
```

Now, since you have the list in memory, lookups should be quick. For example to find if you have any entries that match the written text, you can do something like this:

```
var matches = words.Where(w => w.Word.StartsWith(myTextBox.Text)).OrderByDescending(w => w.Weigth);
```

Now matches will contain a list of all your words that start with the same text as written in the textbox, and will already be sorted so that the words with the highest weight appear first in the list.

Comment: Thanks, what a quick response, i'm very new to c# and never quite know which options to apply to a particular problem as there are so many different ways to get to a solution.

Comment: @Oyvind Knobloch-Brathen - Can you explain the last 'var matches... statement. I can't find a reference to .Where or .StartsWith. May be I'm not looking hard enough :0)

Comment: Look for documentation of extension methods on `IEnumerable`. It's a part of LINQ that was introduced in .NET 3.5 and is documented in abundance around the internet :)

Comment: Hi Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen, I've had a good play with the code but I'm having trouble with the last else statement'else words.Add( new Words{ Word = line.Replace("#",""), Weight = weight});' when i check it with 'Debug.WriteLine(words[0]);' it's returning the text "namespace.form1+Words", where namespace is the namespace

Comment: @Garry - That is correct. Remember that words[0] is an instance of the Words class, and printing it will run the default ToString method that only print the class and namespace name. Either override ToString inside Words, or print words[0].Word and words[0].Weight separately.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm running ahead without grasping the basics. I will have to rain myself in a little ;0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom XML format or a database table to do this stuff.

Comment: Thanks abmv, the text file is provided and cannot be altered. It could be converted to another document such as xml or a database. Especially as the text file remains constant for months if not years.

Comment: u said store the data,so you can as above poster made a class for it save the processed object in xml etc...